# Why can't install the weixin apk in my debian?

Tags: software-installation, android, adb, emulators

I have installed anbox.

```
anbox version
anbox 0.0~git20181014-1~bpo9+1-Debian
```

Have a try to install an apk after downloading `weixin7013android1640.apk`.

```
adb install  weixin7013android1640.apk
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: no devices/emulators found
```

Why no emulator found in my os?How to fix it?
Do as  @A.B suggested to follow official manual:
[official manual](https://salsa.debian.org/zhsj/anbox/-/blob/master/debian/README.Debian)

```
sudo wget  https://build.anbox.io/android-images/2018/07/19/android_amd64.img -o   /var/lib/anbox/android.img
sudo systemctl start anbox-container-manager.service
sudo systemctl status anbox-container-manager.service 
    anbox-container-manager.service - Anbox Container Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/anbox-container-manager.service; enabled;
    Active: active (running) since 
systemctl --user start  anbox-session-manager.service
systemctl --user status  anbox-session-manager.service
    anbox-session-manager.service - Anbox Session Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/anbox-session-manager.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since
```

Try it with one sample apk.

```
  wget https://f-droid.org/FDroid.apk
  adb install FDroid.apk
```

[image]
Success.
Now it is time to install the weixin apk.

```
adb install  weixin7013android1640.apk       
Failed to install weixin7013android1640.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

Please download the weixin apk from 
[download weixin apk to install with adb in your debian](https://dldir1.qq.com/weixin/android/weixin7013android1640.apk)

https://dldir1.qq.com/weixin/android/weixin7013android1640.apk

Every coder here install the `weixin7013android1640.apk` successfully with adb command on your debian,please paste all your steps ,i install it successfully following your steps ,then get 500 points for the issue.

Comment: Could add the output of `systemctl status anbox-container-manager.service` ?

Comment: You should start by reading [`/usr/share/doc/anbox/README.Debian`](https://salsa.debian.org/zhsj/anbox/-/blob/master/debian/README.Debian).

Comment: @A.B,please try it in your debian and paste what you do.

Comment: If the FDroid.apk from the README.Debian installs and runs, then the issue is not in anbox installation but either in the apk you're trying to use, or in the emulation capabilities.

Comment: my initial comment was about this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/581986/2 which changed a lot meanwhile. If now the specific apk causes a problem, I'd hardly know how to do better.

Comment: I rewrite many content instead of the apk,the target apk--weixin apk remains unchanged at all.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, did you restart the system after installing Anbox?

You should first start the `anbox-container-manager.service`. You can do this by -

`systemctl start anbox-container-manager.service`

This requires some DKMS modules. So load them before starting the service by -

```
# modprobe ashmem_linux
# modprobe binder_linux
```

If you don't load these before starting the anbox service, it will restart your system and try to obtain them. Now, you need to start some more services before you can enable the `anbox-container-manager.service`.

Start the `systemd-networkd` service by -

`systemctl start systemd-networkd`

Finally, you can start `anbox-container-manager.service` and then install your apks using adb

Comment: sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd

Comment: @it_is_a_literature thanks, missed it

Comment: Please try to install  weixin7013android1640.apk  to check what happen in your debian.

Answer (score 1):

After you have installed *anbox* application, you have to start it, or better, start its **service** and load its **modules**.
You can refer to this guide **[1]** as starting point.

---

**[1]** https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Anbox#Installation